# How to make Jenkins deploy docker images creating containers?

Tags: docker, jenkins, containers

Has been time I was searching about it, but I failed, so I would like suggestion for how to do it.

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                        CONTAINER             |
|                                      +-------------+         |
|      +------------+                  |             |         |
|      |            |    Deploy        |  APP - 1    |         |
|      |  Jenkins    ----------------->              |         |
|      |            |                  |             |         |
|   |-----+docker   |                  +-------------+         |
|   |  +------------                                           |
|   |    CONTAINER  |             +-------------+              |
|   |               |             |             |              |
|   +               |  Deploy     |   APP-2     |              |
|  docker            ------------->             |              |
|                                 |             |              |
|                                 +-------------+              |
|  OS SYSTEM (LINUX)                 CONTAINER                 |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I have a Linux with Docker installed and a Jenkins running inside docker with possibility to make docker in docker, that is, I mirrored bin/docker for him.

My goal is make this Jenkins deploy other images thus creating container and running it.
for example, I have a git repository with dockerfile, I pull, but when I need to create this container I failed.

Anyone can suggest a "right"/"precise" article to help? I appreciate it :)

Comment: This concept is called docker in docker. Try this one to search you will get lot of article. You can try https://github.com/jpetazzo/dind

Comment: Hi Taybur, I read an article about Docker in Docker, how it is a bad idea, so I was thinking  something docker out of docker, is it possible?

Comment: This article help me to understand my failed - https://medium.com/@schogini/running-docker-inside-and-outside-of-a-jenkins-container-along-with-docker-compose-a-tiny-c908c21557aa